# Kivy evento com teclado

Tags: python, teclado, python-kivy

Estou criando um piano com kivy esta funcionando tudo bem, mas só com o clique do mouse no Button , Quero saber como faço para ao digitar uma tecla o Button ser executado sem que eu tenha que clicar com o mouse

```py
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class Piano(App):
    def build(self):
        c = Button(text='C',font_size=30,on_release=self.do)
        d = Button(text='D', font_size=30, on_release=self.re)
        e = Button(text='E', font_size=30, on_release=self.mi)
        f = Button(text='F', font_size=30, on_release=self.fa)
        g = Button(text='G', font_size=30, on_release=self.sol)
        a = Button(text='A', font_size=30, on_release=self.la)
        b = Button(text='B', font_size=30, on_release=self.si)
        box = BoxLayout()
        box.add_widget(c)
        box.add_widget(d)
        box.add_widget(e)
        box.add_widget(f)
        box.add_widget(g)
        box.add_widget(a)
        box.add_widget(b)
        return box`

    def do (self,c):
        som = SoundLoader.load('Songs/do.wav')
        som.play()
    def re (self,d):
        som = SoundLoader.load('Songs/re.wav')
        som.play()
    def mi (self,e):
        som = SoundLoader.load('Songs/mi.wav')
        som.play()
    def fa(self,f):
        som = SoundLoader.load('Songs/fa.wav')
        som.play()
    def sol (self,g):
        som = SoundLoader.load('Songs/sol.wav')
        som.play()
    def la (self,a):
        som = SoundLoader.load('Songs/la.wav')
        som.play()
    def si (self,b):
        som = SoundLoader.load('Songs/si.wav')
        som.play()




if __name__ in '__main__':
    Piano().run()
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta e insira o código que já tem atualmente. Da maneira que está, ficará difícil responder exatamente o que precisa.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro, você precisará importar a classe `Window` ao seu código:

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
```

Assim, você poderá obter os eventos do teclado a partir do método [`request_keyboard`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.core.window.html#kivy.core.window.WindowBase.request_keyboard). O primeiro parâmetro do método é uma função *callback* que será executada quando o teclado for fechado; o segundo parâmetro será o objeto que estará associado ao teclado. Assim, acredito que você possa fazer dentro da sua classe:

```
class Piano(App):
    def build(self):

        self.keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self.keyboard_closed, self)
        self.keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self.on_key_down)

        c = Button(text='C',font_size=30,on_release=self.do)
        d = Button(text='D', font_size=30, on_release=self.re)
        e = Button(text='E', font_size=30, on_release=self.mi)
        f = Button(text='F', font_size=30, on_release=self.fa)
        g = Button(text='G', font_size=30, on_release=self.sol)
        a = Button(text='A', font_size=30, on_release=self.la)
        b = Button(text='B', font_size=30, on_release=self.si)
        box = BoxLayout()
        box.add_widget(c)
        box.add_widget(d)
        box.add_widget(e)
        box.add_widget(f)
        box.add_widget(g)
        box.add_widget(a)
        box.add_widget(b)

        return box`

    def keyboard_closed(self):
        pass
```

O retorno do método será uma instância de [`Keyboard`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.core.window.html#kivy.core.window.Keyboard), portanto você poderá fazer o *bind* com o evento `on_key_down` para um método seu:

```
class Piano(App):
    def build(self):

        self.keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self.keyboard_closed, self)

        c = Button(text='C',font_size=30,on_release=self.do)
        d = Button(text='D', font_size=30, on_release=self.re)
        e = Button(text='E', font_size=30, on_release=self.mi)
        f = Button(text='F', font_size=30, on_release=self.fa)
        g = Button(text='G', font_size=30, on_release=self.sol)
        a = Button(text='A', font_size=30, on_release=self.la)
        b = Button(text='B', font_size=30, on_release=self.si)
        box = BoxLayout()
        box.add_widget(c)
        box.add_widget(d)
        box.add_widget(e)
        box.add_widget(f)
        box.add_widget(g)
        box.add_widget(a)
        box.add_widget(b)

        return box`

    def keyboard_closed(self):
        pass

    def on_key_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        teclas = {
            "c": self.do,
            "d": self.re,
            "e": self.mi,
            "f": self.fa,
            "g": self.sol,
            "a": self.la,
            "b": self.si,
        }

        if keycode[1] in teclas:
            teclas[ keycode[1] ]()
```

Assim, quando uma tecla for pressionada, o método `on_key_down` será executado, verificando se a tecla é uma das previstas pela aplicação e, se for, executa o método que toca o áudio.

**Referência**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280341/how-do-you-check-for-keyboard-events-with-kivy